# Not seeing set throttled speed in Charles Proxy

Tags: proxy

I am using [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) for SSL Proxying, and for throttling. I have verified that everything is set up properly, and I am able to examine traffic to my Android device. I'm using the built-in **56 kbps Modem** profile, and I have noticed that when I throttle, I am not seeing the expected speeds in the [Ookla SpeedTest app](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/android), but when I run it in Chrome at speedtest.net, I see the expected throttled speeds.

Here are the results I got

**SpeedTest app**

- Un-throttled: 40.4 Mbpsꜜ (and 11.6 Mbpsꜛ)
- Throttled: 41.1 Mbpsꜜ (and 11.2 Mbpsꜛ)

**In Chrome**

- Un-throttled: 11.34 Mbpsꜜ
- Throttled: 0.03 Mbpsꜜ

I checked some other apps on my device and verified that downloads are slow there as well. Why is the traffic in the native SpeedTest app not throttled?

Comment: Interesting... Have you tried to raise this issue to Charles Proxy team?